# What is the recommended way to deploy a .NET Core app into Heroku?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, heroku, web-deployment

I want to deploy an ASP.NET Core 3.1 web app into the Heroku platform. 
After searching in google and following a bunch of articles I am still getting an error.

> Deploy fails with "[ERROR]: Failed to deploy"

Can someone recommend me the latest working way of deploying a .NET app into Heroku?

Comment: can please error message

Answer (score 1):

You need to use correct heroku build pack for asp.net core.

This build pack maybe helps you.

https://github.com/jincod/dotnetcore-buildpack